# Get DFS folder target (local server path) from a DFS path in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have a DFS folder path...

```
\\domain.name\SharesRoot\DFSShare
```

I need to get the actual folder target of this root link or in other words the local server path that DFSShare is targetting

The local server path/folder target is as follows

```
\\MyServer\Share\MyShare
```

I've successfully used the [NetDfsGetClientInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524810(v=vs.85).aspx) method to retrieve SOME of the needed information from the given DFS path

The DFS_STORAGE_INFO object that this method populates gives me the following data

- State: *irrelevant data*
- ServerName: 'MyServer'
- ShareName: 'SharesRoot'

While the ServerName is what I'm looking for, the ShareName does not help me at all.

**I need to find out what the path is on** `MyServer` **that the DFS path** `\\domain.name\SharesRoot\DFSShare` **is targetting**

[NetDfsGetInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524812(v=vs.85).aspx) gives me 1168 error, so that method is not helping, and I'm yet to try [NetDfsEnum()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524809(v=vs.85).aspx), however my hopes aren't high seeing as it populates the same structs as the [NetDfsGetClientInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524810(v=vs.85).aspx)... if anyone has any other leads here I'd be incredibly grateful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems the [NetDfsGetClientInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524810(v=vs.85).aspx) is indeed the answer for my particular needs.

The issue is that its behavior changes based on whether it's called on a DFS client machine versus if it's called on the DFS server machine.

On a client machine the call returns a DFS_STORAGE_INFO object with the following data:

- ServerName: 'MyServer'
- ShareName: 'Share'

All that's needed once this is returned is to append the subpath, which can be stripped out using the entry path of the DFS_INFO_3 object and the original path used in the [NetDfsGetClientInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb524810(v=vs.85).aspx) call

Answer (score 2):

I found that on the client I needed to access the DFS path first, then something in Windows caches this, so that when I then perform the NetDfsGetClientInfo() I get the underlying path (not the dfs path)

So this is what worked for me:

```
string dfsPath = "\\domain.name\SharesRoot\DFSShare";

//by doing Directory.Exists we access the DFS path, causing Windows to resolve it
if (Directory.Exists(dfsPath))
{
    string dfsPath = DFS.GetSharePath(dfsPath);
    MessageBox.Show($"{dfsPath});
}
```

This is the class code I found elsewhere (not mine)

```
  class DFS
{
    #region Import
    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "NetApiBufferFree")]
    public static extern uint NetApiBufferFree(IntPtr Buffer);

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int NetDfsGetInfo(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string EntryPath,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ServerName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ShareName,
        int Level,
        out IntPtr Buffer);

    [DllImport("Netapi32.dll")]
    public static extern int NetDfsGetClientInfo(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string EntryPath,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ServerName,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string ShareName,
        int Level,
        out IntPtr Buffer);

    #endregion

    #region Structures

    public struct DFS_INFO_3
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string EntryPath;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string Comment;
        public UInt32 State;
        public UInt32 NumberOfStorages;
        public IntPtr Storages;
    }

    public struct DFS_STORAGE_INFO
    {
        public Int32 State;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string ServerName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        public string ShareName;
    }

    #endregion

    const int DFS_VOLUME_STATE_OK = 0x00000001;
    const int DFS_VOLUME_STATE_ONLINE = 0x00000004;
    const int DFS_STORAGE_STATE_ONLINE = 0x00000002;
    const int DFS_STORAGE_STATE_ACTIVE = 0x00000004;

    public static String GetSharePath(String DFSPath)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DFSPath))
        {
            IntPtr Buffer = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("User : {0}, Domain= {1}", Environment.UserName, Environment.UserDomainName);
                Console.WriteLine("Path is {0}", DFSPath);
                int Error = NetDfsGetClientInfo(DFSPath, null, null, 3, out Buffer);
                Console.WriteLine("Error code {0}", Error);
                if (Error == 0)
                {
                    DFS_INFO_3 DFSInfo = (DFS_INFO_3)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Buffer, typeof(DFS_INFO_3));
                    if ((DFSInfo.State & DFS_VOLUME_STATE_OK) > 0)
                    {
                        String SubPath = DFSPath.Remove(0, 1 + DFSInfo.EntryPath.Length).TrimStart(new Char[] { '\\' });
                        for (int i = 0; i < DFSInfo.NumberOfStorages; i++)
                        {
                            IntPtr Storage = new IntPtr(DFSInfo.Storages.ToInt64() + i * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(DFS_STORAGE_INFO)));
                            DFS_STORAGE_INFO StorageInfo = (DFS_STORAGE_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(Storage, typeof(DFS_STORAGE_INFO));
                            if ((StorageInfo.State & DFS_STORAGE_STATE_ACTIVE) > 0)
                            {
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SubPath))
                                {
                                    return String.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}", StorageInfo.ServerName, StorageInfo.ShareName);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return (String.Format(@"\\{0}\{1}\{2}", StorageInfo.ServerName, StorageInfo.ShareName, SubPath));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (Error == 2662)
                    return DFSPath;
            }
            finally
            {
                NetApiBufferFree(Buffer);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String GetShareName(String SharePath)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SharePath))
        {
            String[] Tokens = SharePath.Trim(new Char[] { '\\' }).Split(new Char[] { '\\' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (2 <= Tokens.Length)
                return Tokens[1];
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```